# FTP asks for authentication on every directory change

Tags: centos, authentication, ftp

I'm setting a virtual web test server for the company I work for. They want to access the different directories using FTP and their Linux accounts. So far, that works well. They want the ftp-root to be `/home`, and then after that access the directories they need to work on. That also works well but the user is asked to reauthenticate every time they change directories.

We are using CentOS with vsftpd. What is the cause of this behavior and can it be changed so that they are only asked to authenticate when the session is initiated?

Comment: You need to help us help you by providing more information. Please edit your question and ads some relevant information like which OS you're using, which ftp daemon you're using are there any relevant log messages ...

Comment: I'm using CentOS with vsftpd.  After many try, i've noticed that it only happens when i try to access a directory im not suppose to have access to. After that, it looks like i have to relog.

Comment: @littleadmin You should append your question, it will be easier to follow.

Comment: The 70s called and they want their transfer protocol back: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie

Comment: As funny as the late 70 comment is and as much as i agree, im an intern here and dont get to decide what protocol they use.  And no, theres no real sysadmin to help me, which make my internship really interesting..and weird when i have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the ftp client you are using, rather than the server configuration, but we can't say for sure without knowing what client tools you are using to access the sever. I suggest you try different client software (winscp, filezilka, ...)

The other possibility is, of the reauthentication request happens when they have not used the FTP connection for a while, is that the connection head dropped in the meantime and it doesn't remember their credentials between connection so needs to ask again. Again using a different client may help, though you could also look into stopping the connection drops (does the client support sending "keep alive" commands? - is the server timing out the sessions (keep-alives will help here, and you might be able to tell the server not to timeout inactive links), or are there deeper connectivity drips?

While you arse investigating, I suggest you consider using SFTP/SCP instead of FTP: it is more secure (especially if you are connecting over three public Internet), can be more efficient (particularly for some documents of you use the built in compression support, causes less issues with firewalls, and you probably already have OpenSSH installed for SSH access and that supports both out of the box.

Comment: Works like a charm when i use fireFTP, which is the client they use here.  So i suppose my problem is solve :)  Thanks for the suggestions.